# Double tabbed layout

Tags: android, android-layout, tabbed, tabbed-view

I've been trying for two days to manage double tabbed layout. Is it possible to do this? Like this ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

Top Tab make it fixed like

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed" 
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

and inner tab

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" 
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

### [See Good tutorial for TabLayout](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Comment: Can you give me more explanation about inner tab ?